# Using a proxy server as a replacement for hosts file

Tags: mac, proxy, hosts

When developing a website, it's often handy to map the domain to 'localhost' in your hosts file so you can use the real url in a browser. However, switching between local and public hosts using the hosts file gets boring pretty fast, even if you use a tool like [gas mask](http://code.google.com/p/gmask/).

I'm wondering if there would be some way to use a proxy server to make things more easy. I want to point my browser to a proxy server that forwards all requests for mydomain.tld to localhost. I've been looking into [glype](http://www.glype.com/), but i can't find a way to make this work using that.

Comment: Glype is not a full HTTP proxy; it's web-based: just a PHP script that fetches webpages on your behalf (and modifies URLs to point to the same script).

Answer (score 1):

Charles works like this. It has a feature called Map Local which will let you list a set of files/folders to replace with files from your local disk. It is nearly zero-config when you run it on Windows.